# How to select row with same id and add its field value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table medicine record with fields

```
Name  qunty    min    expiry
a       2       3     14/2/2012
b       4       1     15/12/2010
a       5       3     16/5/2012
```

I have to select medicine which has  qunty less than min value . Two rows can exist with same name but with different expiry . So in that condition i have to add qunty of same name row and than match with min value .

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Not yet i don't know how it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one,

```
SELECT  Name, `min`, SUM(qunty) totalQunty
FROM    medicine
GROUP BY NAME, `min`
HAVING SUM(qunty) < `min`
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd22d/1)

in that case i have also a question with you, are `min` values constant for the same name?

Comment: yeah min values is constant for the same name.

Comment: error occurs Unknown column 'min' in 'having clause' and min column exist over there

Comment: @chetan yes that's for my original answer, try my updated answer.